# Gradle using terminal with Android Studio install on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, android-studio

Can not get the terminal commands to work with gradle. I trying to get Gradle to work outside of Android Studio as a prelude to scripting up various flavors of my app. I got the flavors to build within Android Studio but I find the interface confusing.

Gradle was installed either with ADT or Android Studio at: /home/mark/.gradle

Would like to use the install of Gradle at /home/mark/.gradle. Would like to avoid the Gradle in the repo since Android Studio updates frequently and their a possibility that I could wind up with two different versions of Gradle that could cause more headaches.

So far I have tried setting the PATH various ways in .bashrc bash.bashrc environment
files. Nothing worked.

Not sure if I put the wrong terms/commands in those files or the files are wrong ones. Tried the gradle term with and with out the dot as well. I would appreciate explicit instructions on terms/commands and in what files.

Thank You in Advance Mark91

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

In .bashrc, I have

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-all/27drb4udbjf4k88eh2ffdc0n55/gradle-2.1/bin
```

Restart terminal, then test `which gradle`